# Can we edit 301 redirects?

Tags: 301-redirect

If we set 301 redirects using a plugin, does Google consider those 301 redirects irrevocable? i.e. even if we updated the redirect's URL target, Google would still only consider the original redirects.

If we removed the redirect plugin and set different 301 redirects in the .htaccess file, would we be able to get Google to acknowledge those new 301 redirects?

Comment: Why would google need to acknowledge 301 redirects at all?  I wpuld expect Google sees a 301 redirect as a strong hint to update its database to remove the link and replace it with the 301 target.

Comment: Are you asking if PageRank (link juice) will be passed to the new target after you change a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will periodically re-check the redirecting URL to see what it is now doing. So you can change what it does and after a time, Google will catch on to it.